# Instance variables that start with `@_`

Tags: ruby

What is the purpose of making instance variables start with an underscore like the following?

```
@_variables_name
```

Comment: There is no community-wide convention like that. That is just the author's own convention. You can only tell given the context of the code.

Answer (score 5):

Ruby does not have a special interpretation of instance variables that start with an underscore, like PHP has a special meaning for vars that start and end with double underscores (e.g. `__FILE__`).

So, `@_instance_var` has no special meaning. Rails internally uses it to distinguish private/protected variables that other should not modify/access.

But, there is no community-wide convention yet. So, you can use the Rail's convention or make up your own use for that.

Comment: so @_ variables means, by rails convention, private protected variables, right?

Comment: I could quibble with your first sentence. The local variable `_` can represent more than one block variable e.g., `|_,_,x|`, whereas other variables used that way (e.g., `|a,a,x|`) will raise `Syntax Error: duplicated argument name`.

Comment: @anyavacy - yeap. Cary, I should have be more specific. No special meaning for instance variables that start with underscore. Updated my answer.